# How to use implemented labels on spaCy for each word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, nlp, spacy

### What I would like to do

I would like to extract word which is given specific label on spaCy, natural language OSS.

[specific labels on spaCy](https://spacy.io/api/annotation)

On the below case, I hope to print the word `English` because the label `LANGUAGE` is selected.

```
English
```

### Problem

There is no sample code for extracting labels on each word.

How can I fix the below error?

```
TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got spacy.tokens.token.Token)
```

### Current Code

```py
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

words = ['America', 'American', 'Christmas', 'English']
words = nlp(words)
for w in words:
    if w.label_=="LANGUAGE":
        print(w) #English
```

### What I tried

I've chacked each label and sample code for visualization.

Additionally, non-sentence input, ` was executable on [the spaCy vizualizer on the web browser](http://American%20NORP%20speaks%20English%20LANGUAGE%20and%20celebrates%20Christmas%20DATE%20in%20America%20GPE%20.).

output

```
American NORP speaks English LANGUAGE and celebrates Christmas DATE in America GPE .
```

This code is from [the sample code on the spaCy homepage](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers).
code

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text = "American speaks English and celebrates Christmas in America."
doc = nlp(text)
displacy.serve(doc, style="ent")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follow:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

words = ['America', 'American', 'Christmas', 'English']
words = nlp('. '.join(words) + '.')
for w in words.ents:
    if w.label_=="LANGUAGE":
        print(w.text) #English
```

Keep in mind that spacy finds named entities in the text by looking at the whole context and grammar. For instance, one named entity could be "The United States of America", which are 4 words. If you wish to look word by word then you would need to give the right grammatical sense to that "text". That is why I have separated the text (your list of words) by using a period after each word.